# Can't add variable into php session

Tags: php, session, configuration, session-variables, session-cookies

I am trying to add variable into session and read that variable in function.

so here is **index.php:**

```
<?php
include("include/config.php");

if(!empty($txt_user) && !empty($txt_pass))
{
    $result=login_func($txt_user,$txt_pass);

    if($result==1)
    {
        header("Location: homepage.php");
    }else{
        $alert_class="alert-danger";
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo("".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."");?>" method='post' class='form-validate' id="test">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="email controls">
                        <input type="text" name='txt_user' placeholder="Kullanıcı Adınız" class='form-control' data-rule-required="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="pw controls">
                        <input type="password" name="txt_pass" placeholder="Şifreniz" class='form-control' data-rule-required="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Giriş Yap" class='btn btn-primary'>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**config.php:**

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
session_start(); 
ob_start();

include("class.php");
include("functions.php");

**connections to db**
?>
```

**functions.php:**

```
function login_func($user,$pass)
{
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_name='$user' AND pass='$pass' LIMIT 1");

  $control_number=mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if(($control_number==1))
  {
    $_SESSION['login_id']=@mysql_result($sql,0,'id');
    $_SESSION['login_name']=@mysql_result($sql,0,'name');
    $_SESSION['login_email']=@mysql_result($sql,0,'email');

    return 1; // true
  }else{
    return 2; //false
  }
}
```

So if i add following commands to homepage.php i get empty result for each echo:

```
   echo $_SESSION['login_id'];
   echo $_SESSION['login_name'];
   echo $_SESSION['login_email'];
```

even also if i do same echo action just in function it doesnt give any output too.

[image: also here are my php session configurations:]

So i am stuck on here and cant find what cause this problem. thanks for your helps.

> please dont worry about syntax errors I think that only problem is using wrong sessions and sessions conf.

Comment: DO NOT USE `mysql_*` FUNCTIONS. They will only make you vulnerable to SQL-injection. Please use `mysqli_*` or prepared queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `$txt_user` and `$txt_pass` variables as [registered globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Unless you are using php 5.3 and below the register_globals is removed from PHP.

Registering globals is a **huge security risk** and should be avoided in any case.

Try using `$_POST['txt_user']` and `$_POST['txt_pass']` instead

Comment: Thank you for comment, I am using php 5.3 and all code working local on server, and also code is old so working on it to upgrade.